# Limit the results with a Teradata SQLquery

Tags: sql, teradata

The SQL below is causing results to drop off because the minimum FYPD is in a prior fiscal year.  The PS_DEPR_RPT table contains 1 line for each asset since there are 12 accounting periods.

The purpose of the query below is to return a asset ID.  The minimum works great if the asset isn't added in a prior period.

```
select  business_unit, asset_id, book, 
min((fiscal_year * 100) + accounting_period) as FYPD

from psfs.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr

where book = 'PERFORM' 
having FYPD between 201901 and 201912
group by 1,2,3
```

Any suggestions on how to return a single asset id from this table for FY 19 and periods 1 thru 12 would be greatly appreciated.  Doesn't seem like it should be so difficult but I'm not getting through the haze today.  Thanks for your help...

Comment: Shaves . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to tell what you are looking for. Maybe it's as simple as filtering in the WHERE clause instead of HAVING `where book = 'PERFORM' 
AND ((fiscal_year * 100) + accounting_period) between 201901 and 201912`

Answer (score 0):

Consider calculating across multiple fiscal year periods with conditional aggregation (moving `WHERE` condition to `CASE` statements):

```
select  business_unit, asset_id, book, 
        min(case 
                 when FYPD between 201701 and 201712
                 then (fiscal_year * 100) + accounting_period
                 else NULL
            end) as FYPD_17,
        min(case 
                 when FYPD between 201801 and 201812
                 then (fiscal_year * 100) + accounting_period
                 else NULL
            end) as FYPD_18,
        min(case 
                 when FYPD between 201901 and 201912
                 then (fiscal_year * 100) + accounting_period
                 else NULL
            end) as FYPD_19

from psfs.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr

where book = 'PERFORM' 
group by 1, 2, 3
```

Should you need the non-null minimum across all *FYPD* columns, run `COALESCE` on result of a CTE [`WITH`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/huc7AEHyHSROUkrYABqNIg/~S4896D1PrzE~yucN7C9SQ) syntax.

```
with cte as (
   -- ...above query...
)
select  business_unit, asset_id, book, 
        coalesce(FYPD_19, FYPD_18, FYPD_17) as FYPD_min    
from cte
```

Comment: @gordon linoff……...You are correct.  I could have done a better job what I was looking for.....

Comment: @fred...…….thanks for the feedback.  I was making it much more difficult than I needed.  I simply removed the accounting period criteria and changed the fiscal year criteria = 2019 and got the results that I needed

Comment: ,,,,,,,,Thanks...……..I simplified it by removing the accounting period criteria and just using the fiscal year criteria.  Sometimes, I think things are harder than they really are...sometimes simpler is better..at least in this case.  Thanks again